# pandas merging columns of frame with partial matches in columnname

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where an excelfile is the source. The excelfile is filled with the answers of a google forms.

The colums I have currently are:

```
Index(['Keeper', 'Linksback', 'linker centrale verdediger',
   'centrale verdediger', 'rechter centrale verdediger', 'rechtsback',
   'linker middenvelder', 'centrale middenvelder', 'rechter middenvelder',
   'linker aanvaller', 'rechter aanvaller', 'Keeper.1', 'Linksback.1',
   'linker centrale verdediger.1', 'rechter centrale verdediger.1',
   'rechtsback.1', 'linker middenvelder.1', 'linker centrale middenvelder',
   'rechter centrale middenvelder', 'rechter middenvelder.1',
   'linker aanvaller.1', 'rechter aanvaller.1', 'Keeper.2', 'Linksback.2'
   ])
```

The names consistent of positions you can have with a certain tactic from a footballteam. There are a lot of positions which overlap (eg. Keeper, Keeper.1, Keeper.2,....)

I want to make a new dataframe where all the values for positions that are the same are in the same column. I want this to be a frame being build in a dynamic way since in the future more tactics could be added to the form, so more partially numbered columns can show up in my sourcefile.

The way I think would be easiest is making dictionaries of every position, which i can then use to add the group of columns i want to the new dataframe.

```
positiondict = {'Keeper':('Keeper','Keeper.1','Keeper.2'), 'Linksback':('Linksback', 'Linksback.1','Linksback.2')}
```

I am now stuck on how to get this dictionary filled in a decent way. The key has to be any position without a number in it, the same positionname with a number has to be added as a value for that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = dict()
for pos in sorted(a):
    if not d.get(pos.split('.')[0]):
        d[pos.split('.')[0]] = [pos.split('.')[0]]
    else:
        d[pos.split('.')[0]].append(pos)

# d
# Out[13]: 
# {'Keeper': ['Keeper', 'Keeper.1', 'Keeper.2'],
#  'Linksback': ['Linksback', 'Linksback.1', 'Linksback.2'],
#  'centrale middenvelder': ['centrale middenvelder'],
#  'centrale verdediger': ['centrale verdediger'],
#  'linker aanvaller': ['linker aanvaller', 'linker aanvaller.1'],
#  'linker centrale middenvelder': ['linker centrale middenvelder'],
#  'linker centrale verdediger': ['linker centrale verdediger',
#   'linker centrale verdediger.1'],
#  'linker middenvelder': ['linker middenvelder', 'linker middenvelder.1'],
#  'rechter aanvaller': ['rechter aanvaller', 'rechter aanvaller.1'],
#  'rechter centrale middenvelder': ['rechter centrale middenvelder'],
#  'rechter centrale verdediger': ['rechter centrale verdediger',
#   'rechter centrale verdediger.1'],
#  'rechter middenvelder': ['rechter middenvelder', 'rechter middenvelder.1'],
#  'rechtsback': ['rechtsback', 'rechtsback.1']}
```

Comment: works like a charm! I was searching in the complete wrong direction with regular expressions and missed the option of using split.